# Watching state from child component React with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

New to React. Just using create-react-app and Material UI, nothing else.
Coming from an Angular background.

I cannot communicate from a sibling component to open the sidebar.
I'm separating each part into their own files.
I can get the open button in the Header to talk to the parent App, but cannot get the parent App to communicate with the child LeftSidebar.

### Header Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationMenu from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/menu';

class Header extends Component {

  openLeftBar = () => {
    // calls parent method
    this.props.onOpenLeftBar();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppBar iconElementLeft={
                <IconButton onClick={this.openLeftBar}>
                  <NavigationMenu />
                </IconButton>
              }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

### App Component -- receives event from Header, but unsure how to pass dynamic 'watcher' down to LeftSidebar Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

// components
import Header from './Header/Header';
import Body from './Body/Body';
import Footer from './Footer/Footer';
import LeftSidebar from './LeftSidebar/LeftSidebar';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super() // gives component context of this instead of parent this
    this.state = {
      leftBarOpen : false
    }
  }

  notifyOpen = () => {
    console.log('opened') // works
    this.setState({leftBarOpen: true});
    /*** need to pass down to child component and $watch somehow... ***/
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
        <div className="App">

          <Header onOpenLeftBar={this.notifyOpen} />

          <Body />

          <LeftSidebar listenForOpen={this.state.leftBarOpen} />

          <Footer />

        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### LeftSidebar Component - cannot get it to listen to parent App component - Angular would use $scope.$watch or $onChanges

```
// LeftSidebar
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';

class LeftNavBar extends Component {
  /** unsure if necessary here **/
  constructor(props, state) {
    super(props, state)

    this.state = {
      leftBarOpen : this.props.leftBarOpen
    }
  }

  /** closing functionality works **/
  close = () => {
    this.setState({leftBarOpen: false});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer open={this.state.leftBarOpen}>
        <IconButton onClick={this.close}>
          <NavigationClose />
        </IconButton>
        <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}

export default LeftSidebar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free your mind of concepts like "watchers". In React there is only `state` and `props`. When a component's state changes via `this.setState(..)` it will update all of its children in `render`.

Your code is suffering from a typical anti-pattern of duplicating state. If both the header and the sibling components want to access or update the same piece of state, then they belong in a common ancestor (App, in your case) and no where else.

(some stuff removed / renamed for brevity)

```
class App extends Component {
  // don't need `constructor` can just apply initial state here
  state = { leftBarOpen: false }
  // probably want 'toggle', but for demo purposes, have two methods
  open = () => { 
    this.setState({ leftBarOpen: true }) 
  }
  close = () => { 
    this.setState({ leftBarOpen: false }) 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header onOpenLeftBar={this.open} />
        <LeftSidebar 
          closeLeftBar={this.close}
          leftBarOpen={this.state.leftBarOpen} 
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now Header and LeftSidebar do not need to be classes at all, and simply react to props, and call prop functions.

```
const LeftSideBar = props => (
  <Drawer open={props.leftBarOpen}>
    <IconButton onClick={props.closeLeftBar}>
      <NavigationClose />
    </IconButton>  
  </Drawer>
)
```

Now anytime the state in `App` changes, no matter who initiated the change, your LeftSideBar will react appropriately since it only knows the most recent props

Answer (score 2):

Once you set the `leftBarOpen` prop as internal state of `LeftNavBar` you can't modify it externally anymore as you only read the prop in the `constructor` which only run once when the component initialize it self.
You can use the [componentWillReceiveProps life cycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) and update the state respectively when a new prop is received.

That being said, i don't think a Drawer should be responsible for being closed or opened, but should be responsible on how it looks or what it does when its closed or opened.

A drawer can't close or open it self, same as a light-Ball can't turn it self on or off but a switch / button can and should.

Here is a small example to illustrate my point:

```js
const LightBall = ({ on }) => {
  return (
    <div>{`The light is ${on ? 'On' : 'Off'}`}</div>
  );
}

const MySwitch = ({ onClick, on }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>{`Turn the light ${!on ? 'On' : 'Off'}`}</button>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lightOn: false
    };
  }

  toggleLight = () => this.setState({ lightOn: !this.state.lightOn });

  render() {
    const { lightOn } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <MySwitch onClick={this.toggleLight} on={lightOn} />
        <LightBall on={lightOn} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```